# How to get the latest row per value?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have the following kusto query to display columns from a SQL table for the past 7 days as follows:

```
customEvents
| where name == "TrackNullColumns"
| project timestamp,    
    Column = tostring(customDimensions["Column"]),
    CurrentNullColumns = toint(customDimensions["CurrentNull"]),
    PreviousNullColumns = toint(customDimensions["PreviousNull"]),
   CurrentRows = toint(customDimensions["CurrentRows"]),
    PreviousRows = toint(customDimensions["PreviousRows"])
| distinct timestamp, Column, CurrentNullColumns, PreviousNullColumns, CurrentRows, PreviousRows
| extend Delta = CurrentNullColumns - PreviousNullColumns
| project timestamp, Column, CurrentNullColumns, PreviousNullColumns, Delta
| order by Delta desc
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What I noticed is that the same column is repeated multiple times to display distinct values. How do I modify this query to display column only once with latest timestamp value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

```
customEvents
| where name == "TrackNullColumns"
| project timestamp,    
    Column = tostring(customDimensions["Column"]),
    CurrentNullColumns = toint(customDimensions["CurrentNull"]),
    PreviousNullColumns = toint(customDimensions["PreviousNull"]),
   CurrentRows = toint(customDimensions["CurrentRows"]),
    PreviousRows = toint(customDimensions["PreviousRows"])
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by Column
| extend Delta = CurrentNullColumns - PreviousNullColumns
| project timestamp, Column, CurrentNullColumns, PreviousNullColumns, Delta
| order by Delta desc
```